# converting an array of arrays of floats to complex numbers

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I've got an list of lists each containing the two parts of a complex number, like this:

```
parts = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

How do I convert them to a list of complex numbers, like this?

```
munged = [1+2i, 3+4i, 5+6i]
```

Comment: Those are not arrays, those are lists.

Comment: In any case, have you tried anything at all? What exactly are you having trouble with? given `part = [1,2]`, do you know how to create the complex number `1 + 2j`? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```py
parts = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

complex_list = [complex(*x) for x in parts]
```

```py
[(1+2j), (3+4j), (5+6j)]
```

Note: Each complex number will be a complex object `(1+2j)`. If you need it to be a string `'1+2j'` or `'1+2i'`; use:

```py
# f"{a}+{b}j" or f"{a}+{b}i"
complex_list = [f"{a}+{b}i" for a, b in parts]
```

```py
['1+2i', '3+4i', '5+6i']
```

Comment: Thanks, hopefully the downvoter will see the edit and correct...

Comment: Perfect and incredibly fast, thanks! I'll accept it as an answer when I'm allowed.

Comment: FYI: `(1+2j)` is not a tuple.  The parentheses are just a convention that Python uses when it displays a complex number.

Comment: _"Each complex number will be a tuple"_ **NO!** It doesn't become a `tuple` just because the string representation is enclosed in parentheses. See what `type(complex_list[0])` gives (spoiler: it's not `tuple`)

Comment: `[complex(*t) for t in parts]` would be cleaner for complex numbers, and if the string is required, then there's no need for generating a complex number at all, just use `[f"{a}+{b}i" for a, b in parts]`. Neither solution needs to involve indexing.

Comment: @ddejohn, and Pranav good points, edited